# Unit root tests and correlation coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

A linear regression is performed as part of some unit root tests such as ADF, ADF-GLS (ERS), and PP.

Should I pay attention to the correlation coefficients (ordinary, adjusted) of the regression?

For example, do poor correlations invalidate any results of these tests?

Or, can I trust the test statistic to incorporate sufficient information, so I can safely ignore the correlation coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your goal is to learn about stationarity, I do not see added value in the correlation coefficient.

For example, the ADF coefficient statistic $T(\hat\rho-1)$, with 
$$\hat\rho=\frac{\sum_ty_ty_{t-1}}{\sum_t y_{t-1}^2}$$ the coefficient of the AR(1) regression, already contains more or less the information contained in the correlation coefficient.